# How do I incorporate WebDAV into my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, webdav

I would like to add WebDAV to my iPhone application.  What is the best way / library to enable this?

Comment: Seems that I asked the same question again :) Did you find any solution in the meantime?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567763/webdav-server-for-cocoa-iphone-and-ipad-running-ios

Answer (score 3):

WebDAV is just an extension to HTTP.  Thus, you can use any of the existing HTTP APIs available on the iPhone to implement WebDAV, assuming that your needs don't require customization to the request/response beyond that which is supported by the underlying API.

There are also a number of Objective-C based WebDAV client APIs.  Maybe one of those will work?  Hard to say, given the lack of details in your question.

I'd start with [this particular trail of clues](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=objective-c+webdav+client&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: "trail of clues"... nice phrase. I have to steal that.