# WebDAV Server for Cocoa iPhone and iPad running iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, webdav

I'm looking for a WebDAV server - best Open Source - for iPhone and iPad for integration in my app. It should be possible to list, download and upload files. I would like to point the server root on the 'Documents' folder of my app, so the methods should be mapped directly to the file system if possible.

On my search through the internet I came around some suggestions, but they did not work for me:

1. touchcode - the WebDAV server part can be found unter 'Experimental' and I was not able to get it running. Maybe someone has a working release of it?
2. iSharing - this seemed to be a commercial solution which now has been dropped by the developer. I was not able to find more info about it.
3. CocoaHTTPServer - an Apple sample project of a simple HTTP Server. Apple employees themselves write non their support list that this would be a good starting point, though I was not able to find a WebDAV addition for it. Maybe there is one?

So that's what I was able to find so far. Hint would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question asks something similar: [How do I incorporate WebDAV into my iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971128/how-do-i-incorporate-webdav-into-my-iphone-application)

Comment: Some historic discussion can be found here: http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/08/cocoa-httpserver-on-iphone.html

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#webdav-server-in-ios-apps it seems to be doing well and active.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the DynamicServer and `iPhoneHTTPServer` projects in `CocoaHTTPServer`. Use `NSFileManager` to get the file contents. You have to use a web browser...